Differences in the behavior of Bit shifting in C
I'm running a simple program to understand how bit shifting operates in C. The expression (temp << n) / 2^n is indeed equivalent to temp as I see. Reasoning this, it seems that the left shift operation effectively multiplies temp by 2^n, and then dividing by 2^n cancels out this multiplication, leaving the original value of temp.
In this simple program, I get temp for n = 4 and 9 but not for n = 12. For n=12, I get 100679. Why is the behavior different for n=12? I see that we shouldnt be having any overflows for n=12 so I'm curious why this is happening.
Here is the code snippet:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "math.h"

int main() {
    uint32_t temp = 5343559;
    printf("%u\n", ((temp << 4)/(uint32_t)(pow(2, 4)) )); 
    printf("%u\n", ((temp << 9)/(uint32_t)(pow(2, 9)) )); 
    printf("%u\n", ((temp << 12)/(uint32_t)(pow(2, 12)) )); 

    return 0;
}

Thank you.

"I see that we shouldnt be having any overflows for n=12" -- This statement is incorrect. temp << 12 will give you the mathematical result of about 22 billion, which is not representable as a uint32_t.

Use <math.h>, not "math.h". Don't assume that %u is the correct format specifier for uint32_t. Don't assume that pow(2, 4) is exactly equal to 16.0, and remember that floating-to-integer conversion truncates. (It's very likely that all your pow() calls do yield exact results, but I don't think it's guaranteed.)

This is why programmers use hex whenever dealing with bit-wise operators and low level stuff. Decimal is a very unhelpful format for determining which bits that are set.

think of your number, 5343559 as its binary representation. Its declared as a unsigned 32 bit number, so it would look like this:
00000000010100011000100101000111

Notice how the most significant bit is only 9 digits from the left side. Therefore, you can only shift left by 9 until carry issues begin to occur.
temp << 4:
00000101000110001001010001110000

temp << 9:
10100011000100101000111000000000

temp << 12
00011000100101000111000000000000

